# PHP Issue with generating a timestamp on windows server - issue online not on dev

Tags: php, windows, datetime, iis, wamp

first time poster so please take it easy on me. I am developing on a windows 7 machine with WAMP Server running and no configuration changes from the defaults. IIS is turned off.

In my site I have a class method to record actions taken by the user. During this method I obtain a timestamp in unix and save it to the database. On the Dev machine, this works fine but when I put it online I get an error.

**HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.**

I traced the issue through the code to this point:

```
// get date stamp
$date = date_create();
$datestamp = date_timestamp_get($date);  // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
```

I have tried this method and the OOP method and works fine locally, but fails on my full server which is a windows server running IIS.

I have painstakenly checked the PHPINFO.php for discrepancies but can't see anything that would affect this setting - any help would be really appreciated.

Kind Regards

Michael

Comment: what version of PHP and Apache do you have on your dev machine, and what version of PHP and IIS is running on the "production" machine?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you must set a date.timezone to make this work in the php.ini as of php 5.3

date.timezone = "Europe/London"

Or a valid timezone string for your localtion